# replace lines from a file using script

Tags: text-processing

I want to alter a few lines in a conf file.For example,the file will have something like:

```
 local    all          all                              md5
#host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
#host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
#host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0             md5
```

Now,I want to "read" these lines and replace them with :

```
local   all         all                               trust
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0             md5
```

So ,

1) uncomment lines that are commented out

2) read the value that they have ( eg md5) ,and if it is different replace it ( eg with trust )

When I say replace from md5 to trust , I don't mean every md5 word in the file , I want only the specific line , which has `local    all   all  md5` to change.

Is something like this possible?

I know that there is a `read` command to read lines but I can't figure how to do this comparison and replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will accomplish what you're looking for.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Remove # signs from the beginning of lines.
sed -i -e 's/^#//' file.txt

# Replace md5 with trust on the specified lines.
sed -i -e '/local *all *all/{s/md5/trust/}' file.txt
```

You could even optimize this into one command if your sed supports multiple expressions on a single command.

```
sed -i -e '/local *all *all/{s/md5/trust/}' -e 's/^#//' file.txt
```

A quick break down of what's happening

`-i` edit files in place

`-e` add the script to the commands to be executed

`'s/^#//'` Is the script `s` tells us to substitute `^#` is the first pattern is what we're searching for and we're replacing it with nothing (So we're deleting it).

Hopefully this will help you build your own sed expressions.

Comment: Couldn't you do this with only one call to `sed`?

Comment: Yes but I broke it down into two for readability. Massive single commands are difficult to read IMO.

Comment: @ZacharyBrady:Ok,great!And what if I wanted to replace `::1/128` with `:1/129` or `0.0.0.129` ?Can you add an example?Thanks!

Comment: @ZacharyBrady:Oh!I forgot.The problem is how to read also for example the `local    all          all                              md5` ?Because with the above answer , you are just replacing every `md5` with `trust`.But , I want only the certain md5 , in certain line.

Comment: @George Updated my answer

Comment: @ZacharyBrady:Ok, nice thanks!What about changing `::1/128`  , or `127.0.0.1/32` to `127.0.0.1/33`?I tried `sed -i -e 's/(127\.0\.0\.1/32)/(127\.0\.0\.1/33)/g'` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @George You need to escape your forward slashes in your patterns and delete the parens. sed -i -e 's/127\.0\.0\.1\/32/127\.0\.0\.1\/33/g'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41913/discussion-between-zachary-brady-and-george).

Comment: `g` doesn't tell sed to *"do this for the whole file"*, it says *do this for the whole pattern space* (pattern space = current line, in this context). It's redundant when the expression is anchored to the start of the line.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you, learn something new every day.

Comment: @ZacharyBrady:Hello,I left you a message in chat.Thanks!